# Meaning of: You can’t beat a bite on a biscuit for a quick and easy sweet treat

Tags: sentence-meaning

Can someone help me to understand this sentence (I made it bold):

> **You can’t beat a bite on a biscuit for a quick and easy sweet treat.** They make me feel good – as long as I don’t eat too many!

The text is from [BBC 6 minute English](https://www.bbc.co.uk/learningenglish/features/6-minute-english/ep-210107)

Is it a proverb? or is there an idiom inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means ***nothing is better than** a biscuit for a quick and easy sweet treat*.

Comment: Being the BBC, of course _biscuit_ is used in the British sense (American - cookie). The additional words _a bite on_ were presumably added for humorous alliteration (3 words beginning with 'b').